# Should I go to the walk-in interview when I haven't gotten my final semester result?

Tags: interviewing, new-job

I am an engineering student. Last week was my last exam paper for my final semester of my 4 year Degree course. My cousin recommended me to go for a walk-in interview for manufacturing engineer position at a company. However, since last week was my last paper, I have no confirmation that I have passed all of my subjects in my final semester. I decided to go to the walk-in interview with my resume and my previous semesters results even though I have not received result for my final semester.

So my question is, should I go to the walk-in interview even though I have not received my final semester result and only using my previous semester result as my credentials?

Comment: Are there any classes you are expecting to fail?

Comment: Go. There is nothing to lose. If you are a potential candidate for a role within the company but you failed an exam then communicate this to the company. You're not bound to anything yet untill you sign a contract with them.

Comment: Go for it.  I got my first full time job, in my field of study, before I even finished my last semester - it was actually like halfway through the last semester.  As Edwin points out above, you have nothing to lose.  You'd be surprised, if it goes well, you might just walk out of the interview on a path to your first position.

Answer (score 8):

I think it is safe to do this. As long as the company knows you're not graduated yet, there should be no issue.

I did this myself, in my country (Belgium) this is quite normal to do, all companies are recruiting people who are in their last year.

When things get as far as a contract proposal, you can always ask what happens if you don't pass all exams.

Comment: I would think most companies are expecting you to pass and asking what if I fail my classes would reflect poorly on the applicant. I would ask something more to the effect of would I have to wait to graduate until I can actually start which would get the save information you desire without them thinking you might be failing classes

Comment: @Daffy: I can understand what you mean, depends on the company culture. Sometimes the honesty and direct communication can be appreciated, sometimes it turns out bad.

Answer (score 4):

Yes go for it.. if the result of the last exam would affect any employment decision for the company than they may well make any potential offer conditional but there's no impediment to going to the interview.